# RowSet Implementation in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, jdbc

I'm trying to use some existing code on Google App Engine, and it appears that there's a problem with my use of the `CachedRowSetImpl` class. I don't see this class in the [JRE Class White List](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist). Does anyone know where to get a `CachedRowSet` implementation when running in the GAE? In Java 7 there is the new class, `RowSetProvider`, which can be used to obtain a `RowSetFactory`, from which can be obtained a cached row set object; but `RowSetProvider` isn't on the white list either! Many thanks for any help!

Update:
I'm not sure of the correct answer for this issue, but in the end I just removed the references to the `CachedRowSetImpl`, and went with the plain `ResultSet`. I wasn't using any of the functionality specific to the cached row set, and so this really wasn't a problem at this time.

Comment: I have the same problem and will likely need to re-implement with the plain vanilla ResultSet too. A bit disappointed in GAE for this.